# What assumptions can I make when using Redis with a single connection from a NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, concurrency, redis, socket.io

I'm using SocketIO on a NodeJS instance with a single connection to a Redis cache. This cache is being used as a means to maintain state in a real time environment.

My premises include that concurrency issues will likely occur due to high volume of transactions occurring, however, I'm not sure exactly which concurrency issues I need to account for...

My initial design implements using Lua scripts and `EVAL` (a script called with `EVAL` is considered an atomic transaction to Redis) in order enable checks on the state of a given key, but aside from this I'm not sure if I need to implement locks anywhere else.

The main concern I have is when SocketIO catches a connection and subsequently an event to execute, what can I guarantee about the Redis `EVAL` that happens in that event. A specific use case:

1) Client A emits an event that is caught by the server

2) Server executes requested event, which includes a call to `EVAL` a Lua script on Redis

3) Client B emits an event that is caught by the server

4) Server executes requested event, which includes a call to the `EVAL` a different Lua script on Redis

Due to the asynchronous nature of NodeJS, am I able to assume that the `EVAL` from Client A will always be received by the Redis server before Client B's? Am I understanding the event loop completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The answer completely depends on your code. Basically yes, for such type of events nodejs will process them in order they appear on the event loop queue.

However, you say that request processing **includes** a call to `EVAL`, that means **if** your processing includes other I/O (like querying persistent database), the order of steps in processing request from a Client A can interleave with steps in processing requests from Client B.

In general, you should try to avoid creating a logic that breaks on concurrency if possible. If something needs to be done in the exact same order, consider creating a processing queues (global queue where next item can be processed only after previous was completed) or localise critical parts in atomic sequences (like LUA script).